# Calling all http requests of the same type from the same method

Tags: javascript, ajax

In a big web application, is there any advantage(s) or disadvantage(s) of using a common javascript **http_get** method in a common .js file like the example below over writing each of them seperately ?

```
function http_get(url, async) {
    var post = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        async: async,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    return post;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd make your code nicer if you just did a call instead of creating a multi-line object every time in the code.

Comment: @Chipster unless you have a different datatype for each response. Then you would just put everything in the parameters instead. Are there any advantages performancewise ?

Comment: That's true. I'd imagine it still would look slightly cleaner, especially if you use it a lot. You wouldn't have to put commonly used values in as parameters either, like if you're using GET all the time, for instance. That would still make it cleaner. I couldn't tell you performance-wise, though.